# What halachic sefarim do sofrim learn?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, safrus

I was told by one of my [Roshei Yeshiva](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_yeshiva) that there are books that are designated for [sofrim (scribes)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sofer_stam). Does anyone know what are the main books they use to review the Halachot and as reference for difference questions that come up?

Answer (score 6):

When I started studying hilchot safrut, I was told to use the *Kesset haSofer* (by R' Schlomo Ganzfried ע"ה) with R' Ya'akov Stern's *Mishnat haSofer*. It can be purchased [here](http://www.nehora.com/sefer-mishnas-hasofer-al-keset-hasofer/).

From others, I have gleaned that while the above contains all that you *need* to know, the following sefarim are good to study as well:

- Rambam: *Hilchot Tefillin*  (from the *Mishneh Torah*)
- R' Yosef Karo and the Rem"a: "Hilchot Tefillin," "Hilchot Mezuzot," and "Hilchot Sefer Torah" (*Shu"A Orach Chaim* and *Yoreh De'ah*) and the *Mishnah Berurah* to "Hilchot Tefillin"
- *Nachalat Shiva'* (for gittin and ketubot)
- *Melechet Shomayim* (R' Seligmann Baer Bamberger)

Comment: Also Kol Yaakov and LeDavid Emet for more of a Sefardi bent

Comment: And Shulchan Aruch Harav for the Chabad practices

Comment: @Efraim or R' Moshe Weiner's *Osios Harav*